# Switching datasets for an existing PowerBI report

Tags: azure, powerbi

So I have some PowerBI reports that currently use data from CSV files. I have made this data available through azure with up to date data. I want to change the data source of this report to the azure data store without having to rebuild the entire reports. Currently tried using the change data source but the change source is greyed out. Therefore stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Write new Power Queries that return the same columns, then open each of your existing Power Queries in the Advanced Editor and replace the query text with the one that hits the new data source.

Comment: I am relatively new to Power BI, how would I write a new query?

Comment: Use the normal Get Data experience: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/where-to-get-data#get-data-in-excel-windows-or-mac